# Как сделать анимацию заднего фона?

Tags: java, android, анимация

Мне нужно, чтобы картинка на заднем фоне экрана двигалась за счет кадровой анимации. Компилируется, но выдаёт ошибку..

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android: layout_height = "fill_parent"
    android: id = "@+id/ll"
    android: orientation = "vertical"
    android: gravity = "center">
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Animation mEnlargeAnimation;
    Animation mShrinkAnimation;
    Animation mPlayUp;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    LinearLayout ll;
    TextView tv;
    Button play;
    Button settings;
    Button about;
    Button exit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MenuActivity.this, R.raw.music);
        mp.start();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);
        about = (Button) findViewById(R.id.about);
        exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

        Animation bg_rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bg_wow);
        ll.startAnimation(bg_rotate);
    }
}
```

Мой файл анимации в res/anim/bg_wow.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:oneshot="false"> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_menu" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_bg" android:duration="200"/>

</animation-list>
```

Comment: Переведите, пж-та, на русский вопрос.

Comment: И добавьте что именно у вас вызывало затруднение. В чём конкретно проблема.

Comment: ЮрийСпб, помогите... Уже не могу ничего сделать...

Comment: Без указания что за ошибка и на какой строке - помочь вам невозможно.